# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: java, c++, winapi, dll, java-native-interface

This is a very interesting problem. I get the mentioned exception after the *native* code prints some of it's statements. The exception thrown is :

```
hookThreadHandle is not NULL

hookThreadHandle is not NULL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: W:\elita\jnitesters\
workspace\c\MyHook\bin\Debug\MyHook.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization r
outine failed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at keylogger.TestKeys.main(TestKeys.java:12)
```

The first two statements `hookThreadHandle is not NULL` is the one from the `dll` whose initialization failed ! Why does it throw the exception after actually finding the `dll` and then printing the statements. ?

And what is `A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed` exception ? What does it signify ?

*Java Code :*

```
package keylogger;

public class TestKeys {
private static int i = 0;
private native void setWinHook();
private native void unregisterWinHook();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //TestKeys o = new TestKeys();

    System.loadLibrary("MyHook"); // load the library that registers the hook


    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleeping for 10 seconds..");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }catch(Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r,"new thread").start();       
 }
}
```

*C Code :*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <w32api.h>
#include "keylogger_TestKeys.h"

static HHOOK handleKeyboardHook = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;
static DWORD hookThreadId = 0;
static HANDLE hookThreadHandle = NULL;
BOOL WINAPI installHook(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpvReserved);

static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

 printf("You pressed the key !\n");

 return CallNextHookEx(handleKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
  LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress = &installHook;
  hookThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, lpStartAddress, NULL, 0, &hookThreadId);
  if(hookThreadHandle == NULL) {
    printf("\nhookThreadHandle is NULL\n");
  } else {
      printf("\nhookThreadHandle is not NULL\n");
   }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_keylogger_TestKeys_unregisterWinHook
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   if(handleKeyboardHook != NULL) {
     UnhookWindowsHookEx(handleKeyboardHook);
     printf("Keyboard hook successfully unregistered !");
   } else {
       printf("Coudn't Unhook the keyboard hook !");
     }
 }

BOOL WINAPI installHook(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {

handleKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, hinstDLL, 0);
MSG msg;

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return msg.wParam;
```

}

What could be the reason ? [Output on the CMD](http://i49.tinypic.com/23ldvg5.jpg)

Comment: May not be directly related to your current problem, but: don't create threads in DllMain. DllMain has a ton of restrictions on what you can safely do with it; per [MSDN manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx), the *only* thing it should do is really simple initialization - eg setting up critical sections, but that's about it. Certainly don't CreateThread or LoadLibrary or anything else, or you'll have all sorts of trouble later on. And at the very least you should be checking the fwdReason before doing *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

`DllMain` is supposed to return a `BOOL` indicating whether it has succeeded. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When the system calls the `DllMain` function with the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` value, the function returns `TRUE` if it succeeds or `FALSE` if initialization fails. If the return value is `FALSE` when `DllMain` is called because the process uses the `LoadLibrary` function, `LoadLibrary` returns `NULL`. (The system immediately calls your entry-point function with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` and unloads the DLL.) If the return value is `FALSE` when `DllMain` is called during process initialization, the process terminates with an error. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

Your function lacks the requisite `return` statement.

Comment: The exception is resolved. why do i get `unsatisfied link error exception....` when it has already found the `dll`